# Troubleshooting Sequential Unsigned Transaction Processing with 200 Validators

Tags: substrate-node, offchain-worker, unsigned

we're attempting to send unsigned transactions from an offchain worker using the validation code snippet provided:

```
ValidTransaction::with_tag_prefix("thea")
            .and_provides(signatures)
            .longevity(1)
            .propagate(true)
            .build()
```

The goal is to have all 200 validators send one transaction each per block, resulting in 200 transactions per block. However, we're encountering a situation where transactions are being executed sequentially, with only 1-3 transactions processed per block.

We're seeking assistance to identify if there's anything in the provided code or configuration that might be causing this sequential execution, and if any adjustments are needed to achieve the intended concurrent execution of all 200 transactions per block.

Comment: Do validators have enough time to propagate the transaction before it becomes invalid?